# Add onclick event to button after document is ready with JS/JQuery selecting by class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events

I have 2 buttons, one + and one - that increments the quantity of items.

I also have a "Price" of the item and a span that displays the price of the item.

What i need is: When the user clicks the + or - buttons, it increments the quantity of items and the total price.

So far my code looks like this:

**HTML:**

```
<input type="number" size="4" class="input-text qty text" title="Cantidad" value="1" name="quantity" min="1" step="1">
<input type="button" class="plus" value="+">
<input type="button" class="minus" value="-">
<span class="price">90.00&nbsp;€</span>
```

**JS**

```
function inc() {

    var price = "price";

    var elems = document.getElementsByTagName('*'), i;

    for (i in elems) {

        var a = document.getElementsByName("quantity")[0].value;

        if((' ' + elems[i].className + ' ').indexOf(' ' + price + ' ') > -1) {

            var valOfItem = parseInt(elems[i].innerHTML);

            var x = a * valOfItem;

            elems[i].innerHTML = x;         
        }
    }
}
```

I haven't tried it yet but i guess everything will be working as soon as i add my func() to the onClick event on those buttons, i was hoping to do it with jQuery after the document is done loading but i'm not sure how.

Any ideas?

Comment: Take a look at [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/houbxgyf/).

Comment: Hey Regent, that is just what i needed, now i just need to change the addition with multiplication and its done. Why not add it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `click` event handlers to `.plus` and `.minus` and calculate sum based on `input` value using `.text()` and `.val()`:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/houbxgyf/1/).

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    var basePrice = parseFloat($(".price").text());

    $(".plus").click(function()
    {
        changeValue(1);
    });

    $(".minus").click(function()
    {
        changeValue(-1);
    });

    function changeValue(sign)
    {
        $("[name='quantity']").val(parseInt($("[name='quantity']").val()) + sign);
        var countValue = $("[name='quantity']").val();
        var newValue = (basePrice * countValue).toFixed(2);
        $(".price").text(newValue);
    }
});
```

Comment: that is almost perfect, what i need is to multiply the price, in this case 90 euros by the amount of items (the number you change with the + or -) sorry if it wasn't clear enough on the original question.

Comment: @Algorista Where the total price should be placed?

Comment: where it says 90 euros, 2 items would be 180, 3 = 270 etc

Comment: @Algorista take a look at [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/houbxgyf/1/). Is it correct now?

Answer (score 3):

Why not just use javascript (in head) to disable the buttons until page load?

```
<script language="text/javascript">  
window.addEventListener("plus", function() { document.getElementById('plus').disabled = false; }, false); 
window.addEventListener("minus", function() { document.getElementById('minus').disabled = false; }, false); 
</script>
```

Then have the buttons disabled by default.

```
<input type="button" class="plus" value="+" disabled="disabled">
<input type="button" class="minus" value="-" disabled="disabled">
```

The downside of this is any non-JS users will be unable to use the site. Then again, that's likely the case already.

Comment: Why would i want to have the buttons disabled by default? What i need is very simple and i thought it was clear in the question: When the user clicks the + or - buttons the total price changes. very simple. Edited for additional clarity.

Comment: I think you may have misread the code. When the buttons are first created, they are disabled, so cannot be interacted with. When the page has finished loading, the javascript will be called, and they will be enabled. Is this not what you wanted?

Comment: You are right, it might work that way, gotta try it out.

Comment: With the edits, it seems I misunderstood the original question. Apologies.