# Uncaught ReferenceError: addToCart is not defined javascript

Tags: javascript

i am using javascript onclick function to make a function but it returns an error
Uncaught ReferenceError: addToCart is not defined i don't know why
here is my code

my javascript code

```
function addToCart(){
  var productname = $('pname').text();
  var productid = $('productid').text();
  var color = $('#color option:selected').text();
  var color = $('#size option:selected').text();
  var quantity = $('#qty').val();
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'json',
    data:{
      color:color,
      size:size,
      quantity:quantity,
      productname:productname,
    },
    url: "cart/data/store"+productid,
    success:function(data)
    console.log(data);
  })
```

and my onclick input

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="addToCart()" value="add to cart">
```

Answer (score 1):

You did `onclick="addToCart()"` which immediately executed the function you should `onclick="addToCart"`.

Comment: Really?! Look at my answer below I'm also doing `onclick="hi()"`! In the onclick attribute you define any valid JavaScript code that will be executed when the element is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably happening because the browser isn't properly loading your function.  I would try adding a console.log above and outside of your function definition to make sure it's being loaded.

More generally, if you're using jQuery, you probably want to attach that `addToCart` onclick handler in Javascript rather than in HTML.  See this question for more details: [Add onclick event to button after document is ready with JS/JQuery selecting by class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25908621/add-onclick-event-to-button-after-document-is-ready-with-js-jquery-selecting-by)

Answer (score 0):

In the case of everything is okay then what you can do is insted of onclick in html

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="cart-btn" value="add to cart">
```

Script:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   function addToCart(){
   //function definition
 }
  $("#cart-btn").click(addToCart);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your `addToCart` function is either not loading or not defined in the global scope!

##### Example 1 (Function defined in global scope)

```js
function hi() {
  alert("hi");
}
```

```html
<button onclick="hi()">Click Me</button>
```

##### Example 2 (onClick function not defined in global scope)

```js
(() => {
  function hi() {
    alert("hi");
  }
})()
```

```html
<button onclick="hi()">Click Me</button>
```